# empty array position getting months

Tags: java

Is this a jdk/jre bug? I reported this when jdk7 was released but never received a feedback, is it normal get an array of 13 positions?

```
String[] months = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getMonths();
System.out.println(months.length + " " + Arrays.toString(months));
```

output:
13 [enero, febrero, marzo, abril, mayo, junio, julio, agosto, septiembre, octubre, noviembre, diciembre, ]

Answer (score 7):

Not a bug. Looking at the javadoc of the source code (
java.text.DateFormatSymbols), it says:

> Month strings. For example: "January", "February", etc. **An array of
>   13 strings (some calendars have 13 months),** indexed by
>   Calendar.JANUARY, Calendar.FEBRUARY, etc.
>
> ```
> String months[] = null;
> ```

Also, `getWeekdays()` method returns 8 values and so on.

```
public final static int JANUARY = 0;
public final static int FEBRUARY = 1;
public final static int MARCH = 2;
public final static int APRIL = 3;
public final static int MAY = 4;
public final static int JUNE = 5;
public final static int JULY = 6;
public final static int AUGUST = 7;
public final static int SEPTEMBER = 8;
public final static int OCTOBER = 9;
public final static int NOVEMBER = 10;
public final static int DECEMBER = 11;
public final static int UNDECIMBER = 12;
```

The API describes `UNDECIMBER` as: *field indicating the thirteenth month of the year. Although GregorianCalendar does not use this value, lunar calendars do.*

Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Fixed_Calendar) for such calendars.

Comment: Good answer! I consider this to be a bug in JavaDoc of getMonths()!

Comment: Yes. There is no javadoc but code doc. I don't see any javadoc on getMonths

Comment: This issue was reported in this [bug](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4146173) which dates way back to 1998 and updated in 2004.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this page:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.java

Some calendar have 13 months like lunar calendar,chinese leap year and that is why java have kept it like this.

Hope your doubt is clear.